# Nexus S and Moto G - can't differentiate layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to solve layout problem - I tested this res/layout/my.xml on Moto G and it was fine, but when I tested it on Nexus S the buttons were too big. I tried res/layout-xhdpi/my.xml (since Moto G is xhdpi and Nexus is just hdpi), but always one of the layouts inflate on both, never different on each (for xhdpi I use for now button with text so I can instantly see if it went on):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:src="@drawable/pil2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:height="80dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:height="130dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:height="90dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxx"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using density resource set qualifiers (e.g., `-hdpi`) on anything other than drawable resources is a serious code smell, as it is almost assured that you will not get what you want. Beyond that, use Hierarchy View to determine what in your layout rules is causing your difficulties.

Comment: This is how it looks on Nexus S: http://oi58.tinypic.com/oko8l1.jpg and this is how it looks on Nexus 5: http://oi59.tinypic.com/1zlgjud.jpg Of course buttons are maade transparent after making them work properly. First button from the top has no function - just placeholder instead of margingTop. I'm reconsidering my UI all the time, but can't get this thing solid so on any device it'll work properly.

Comment: It would appear that you are trying to make the "buttons" shown on that PNG/JPEG/whatever background be clickable. Your approach is not going to be reliable, as the buttons have nothing to do with that overall background.

Comment: All I want is to make buttons from background PNG react so the pilot really does its function (has clickable open/close door areas). What would You recommend then to use instead? It can't be that much hard - I've seen much more complicated stuff to work really well.

Comment: "What would You recommend then to use instead?" -- see if somebody wrote the equivalent of the old HTML `<map>` tag for imagemaps for Android. Or see what modern Web approaches would be, then figure out how to translate that into Android stuff, probably using `Canvas`. "It can't be that much hard" -- without a library, and for somebody relatively new to Android? My guess is that it would take months to come up with something that looked good. Your original approach would not look good IMHO (rectangular flash as touch feedback over a non-rectangular button).

Comment: So there's no way to make clickable areas on ImageView? Quite a strech for an app like this (simple one, I supposed).

Comment: "So there's no way to make clickable areas on ImageView?" -- nothing built into Android that operates at a high level. There is no doubt that some people have solved this problem, but whether there is a reusable solution that you can apply is the big question. At a low level, you are responding to touch events and drawing some irregular overlay on top of your irregular button to indicate the various highlight states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I went with that solution: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/

Ultimately, it works perfectly on each device and implements rather quickly. Thanks for all responses!

Answer (score 1):

In the Values folder there is dimen.xml file, and there is 3 values folders(values, values-v11, values-v14).If you don't have dimens.xml file in these folders then you can create dimens.xml file for them, So you can give button width and height different different for different devices. Like this:-
For example:- For values folder.

```
 <dimen name="button_width">16dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="button_height">16dp</dimen>
```

For values-v11

```
 <dimen name="button_width">26dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="button_height">26dp</dimen>
```

For values-v14

```
 <dimen name="button_width">36dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="button_height">66dp</dimen>
```

Now in main xml

```
android:layout_width="@+dimen\button_width"
android:layout_height="@+dimen\button_height"
```

I hope your problem will solve.

Comment: I think it can solve problem for these two devices, but how can I know now if it will work properly on other devces?Is it more more API-version-related problem or device-oriented?

Comment: no it will solve your problem for all type of devices like hdpi devices, 7 inch tablets, and 10 inch tablets also...